# Using React's Containment Composition, is `props.children` always of type Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, react-props

When I use what I refer to as content injection in React, I typically follow the example provided by the React docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

When doing this, and referring to `props.children` inside the wrapper component. I can always use `props.children` as an array of objects.

I also am aware that in the past React has referred to props.children as an opaque data structure. So there is no need to reference that in this question. I get it.

---

**My Question Expanded:** If I'm only using `props.children` to do content injection, can I rely on the data type always being an array of objects. Or is there something that could happen to where this is not true?

---

For instance: In the following file [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactivate-containment?file=index.js)

My concern is that I may want to work with that data as an array and I want to know if something could be added in between the `<ContainmentWrapper>` tags that could possibly change the type that I get to work with.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Looking at the docs you should use the `React.Children` methods, so I don't think you can count on `props.children` to always be an array. It might be, but they clearly want to keep it an implementation detail which might change in the future, so I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: And it has changed over time. I guess my concern in this case is specifically around containment and not other uses of `props.children` I would also say that considering I don't upgrade to a new major version of React, am I safe counting on it being an array?

Comment: Why not use the [`React.Children.toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) method? I think that would solve your uncertainties.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Just ran across this cross referencing other similar questions. I still have this burning desire to not use it and feel safe knowing that when using containment I don't have to add an additional check or implicitly convert something that may always be an array to an array. But this is something I will take in advisement if I can't find a good answer that makes me feel confident!